# Create an editable table using WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Maybe this is not the right forum for my question, but I'll try anyway.
I am creating an application where I want the user to be able to fill in values in a table/matrix. The values are then going to be saved to a database I have set up. I want to build this application using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). I watched the following video on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i4mYXSaD4w and it shows very well what features I want my own application to have. The problem is, the example in the video is made in Winforms...

So, my question, which can be split into three parts, is: 
Is there a way to build something equal, similar or better, in WPF? 
What/which control(s) should I use? Grid? DataGrid?
How do I use this control?

I am new to WPF, and do not have a good picture of what controls to use. I have read many questions about WPF's DataGrid on StackOverflow as well as other QnA's, but I couldn't understand how to do what I wanted, or even if it was possible. Therefore, I'm very thankful to anyone who can explain and lead me onto the right track.

Comment: Yes, whatever you can do in winforms, you can do the same or much better in WPF. However your question is not in a proper format for StackOverflow. You need to come up with a specific question about a specific functionality or piece of code. As currently written, your question can be classified as `Too Broad` or `Primarily Opinion Based` in StackOverflow.

Comment: OK @HighCore, thank you for letting me know. Where would you recommend I ask a question like this?